# Prove the equivalence between two definitions of graph entropy

Tags: graph-theory, information-theory

I am trying to prove that the following two definitions are equivalent.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the collection of all maximal independent sets of the graph, and $\mathcal{B}$ denote the collection of independent sets of the graph. Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in $V$ with a fixed distribution $P$, and $Y$ takes values in collection of independent sets. Prove that
$$
\min_{X,Y:Y\in \mathcal{A}} I \left(X;Y\right)=\min_{X,Y:Y\in \mathcal{B}} I \left(X;Y\right),
$$
where $X \in Y$ with probability 1, i.e, if $Y=J$ for some independent set $J$,then $P\left(X \in J|Y=J\right)=1$.

Can anyone guide me in proving this ? Why would the minimum be achieved at a maximal independent set in the R.H.S ?

Answer (score 0):

It's down to the minimisation. Rough idea - First recall that graph entropy is defined given the graph *and* the probability distribution of $X$. Let $Y_1$ be such that it takes values on disjoint independent sets, and $Y_2$ such that it rakes values on maximal independent sets. Note that there exists a many-one deterministic function $f:\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ such that $Y_2 = f(Y_1)$. This immediately establishes that $H(X|Y_2) = H(X|f(Y_1)) \ge H(X|Y_1)$, which leads to the inequality $I(X;Y_1) \ge I(X|Y_2)$.

Now for any $Y_1$ raking values on independent sets, there exists a $Y_2$ taking values only on maximal independent sets such that the above inequality is satisfied. This means that there exists a RV that minimises the above expression and takes values only on maximal independent sets. Voila.

Comment: However, we are taking minimum over special $Y_1$ and corresponding special $Y_2=f\left(Y_1\right)$. Then how does the above relation hold when we take minimum over all $Y_1$ and all $Y_2$ ?

Comment: In essence, for every candidate solution to the optimisation problem $\min I(X;Y)$ in the set $\mathcal{B} - \mathcal{A}$, there exists a candidate in $\mathcal{A}$ that attains a lower (or the same) value. Thus, *an* optimal solution exists in $\mathcal{A}$, and the optimal value may be attained in the restricted problem.

Comment: I don't think the above explanation you gave would be valid for every candidate in $\mathcal{B}$. You said $Y_1$ takes values on disjoint independent sets, not the collection of independent sets. You are thus considering only special candidate in $\mathcal{A}$ not every candidate.

Comment: @AshokVardhan I don't think disjointness is all that important in the argument above, but I agree that this argument needs to be cleaned up. I'm guessing you see the intuition behind it - I can relate any RV on independent sets to a RV on maximal independent sets via a function that forgets some structure in the graph, and hence is a 'cruder' description of $X$. In conjunction with $P(X \in Y)=1$, one should be able to establish the data processing markov chain $X-Y_1-Y_2$. Do let me know if you come up with another argument. I'll post an improved version of this once I get time to work on it.